# WinForm not receiving WM_CLOSE from external program

Tags: c#, winforms, qprocess

With the following, I get `WM_CLOSE` winproc events when they happen within the application such as clicking the [x] or alt+f4, but when an external program* sends the `WM_CLOSE` message, it is not received

```cs
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SDPL
{
    public class SDPL : Form
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ApplicationContext MainContext = new ApplicationContext();
            MainContext.MainForm = new SDPL(ref MainContext);
            Application.Run(MainContext);
        }

        private ApplicationContext Context;
        private const int WM_CLOSE = 0x0010;
        private const int WM_QUIT = 0x0012;

        public SDPL(ref ApplicationContext MainContext)
        {
            Context = MainContext;

            SuspendLayout();
            AutoScaleDimensions = new SizeF(6F, 13F);
            AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
            ClientSize = new Size(271, 31);
            MaximizeBox = false;
            MinimizeBox = false;
            Name = "StreamDeck Plugin Executable Launcher";
            ShowInTaskbar = true;
            SizeGripStyle = SizeGripStyle.Hide;
            Text = "StreamDeck Plugin Executable Launcher";
            ResumeLayout(false);
            PerformLayout();

            FormClosing += SDPLHiddenWindow_FormClosing;
        }

        private void SDPLHiddenWindow_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Form Closing", "Form Closing", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            Context.ExitThread();
        }

        [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case WM_CLOSE:
                    MessageBox.Show("Form Closing from WM_CLOSE", "Form Closing", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                    break;
                case WM_QUIT:
                    MessageBox.Show("Form Closing from WM_QUIT", "Form Closing", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                    break;
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```

*: `The WM_CLOSE` is sent from an application using QT's [`QProcess`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html)'s [`Terminate`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#terminate) method.

Comment: You might want to use `Debug.WriteLine` instead of `MessageBox.Show` for debugging this.  Have you looked at things with Spy++ to see if your window is actually getting the `WM_CLOSE`?  Have you tried writing a (second) small test app that sends your other app a `WM_CLOSE`

Comment: To what handle is the QT app sending (posting) the message? To the Process one, maybe?

Comment: Flydog57, I have not, but that is the next step I plan to take. Jimi, I do not know. The hosting program is a 3rd party application.

Comment: A test is pretty simple to make. Get the window handle: `Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("[Your app name]").FirstOrDefault();`  check if null then `PostMessage(process.MainWindowHandle, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);`. Your app, using the `WndProc` you have here, will show the message box.

Comment: What do you mean with *the hosting program*? Is your Form(s) *embedded* in another applications? Who's handling the message loop? Maybe the host is eating up the messages directed to your Forms.

Comment: Does your FormClosing handler get called? WM_CLOSE is not guaranteed on a Form I think. For instance, MS Docs say: The Form.Closed and Form.Closing events are not raised when the Application.Exit method is called to exit your application.